# Fresh clone of googleads-php-lib already fails to open files

Tags: php, google-api

I just made a fresh clone from the googleads-php-lib from https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib.

The tutorial says I have to run getRefreshToken.php but doing this I already get a warning and and error:

```
Failed opening required 'Google/Api/Ads/AdWords/Lib/AdWordsUser.php'
```

The file exists. I know I can start now to play with the path to fix it.

But should this not be all correct? Maybe I am doing somerthing else wrong...

Comment: Do you actually get two messages (a warning *and* an error)? I see one, where is the other? May the problem is a permission issue?

Comment: Yes there is also a warning: 

Warning: require_once(PATH/googleads-php-lib/src/../../Common/ExampleUtils.php): failed to open

It's all 777 permissened...

Comment: I'm assuming you put `PATH` on there and that is not actually part of the error? Are you sure the file exists where that script is looking? Actually follow the path from the script doing the require to where it is expecting the file to be. It could easily be going up two directories (`../../`) when the files exist up only one or under the same path as the loading script.

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem. The examples work with diferent path...Google should fix that to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The examples from the Github Clone try to find the library files under `src/Google/...` but in the clone it is located under `lib/Google/...`

Folder 'src' needs to be renamed to 'lib'.

GutHub Issue: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/pull/39